# Adding tooltips/hotspots to 360 image viewer

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios

I have a image rotator that is used in my site but now i need to be able to add hot spots that to certain angles. This is the plugin I use.
 
http://blog.stableflow.com/jquery-plugins/360-degrees-product-view/#comments
Has anyone used this before and been able to tweek it to add hotspots?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked through the plugin code and it doesn't support using image maps, so I extracted out the essential code you need, and added a big yellow dot to the third image that you can hover over - [here is a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/g2Shg/).

HTML

```
<div id="product" style="width: 640px; height: 480px; overflow: hidden;">
    ...
    <img src="03.jpg" usemap="#img03" />
    <map name="img03" width="640" height="480">
        <area shape="circle" coords="366,154,65" href="#" title="Yellow Dot!" />
    </map>
    ...
</div>
```

CSS

```
.notseen {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Script

```
// original: http://blog.stableflow.com/jquery-plugins/360-degrees-product-view/
// No need to include the plugin, this is a simplified version of it

jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    var $product = $('#product'),
        $imgs = $product.find('img'),
        imageTotal = $imgs.length - 1,
        clicked = false,
        widthStep = 4,
        currPos,
        currImg = 0,
        lastImg = 0;
    $imgs.bind('mousedown', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // prevent dragging images
    })
        .filter(':gt(0)').addClass('notseen');

    $product.bind('mousedown touchstart', function (e) {
        if (e.type == "touchstart") {
            currPos = window.event.touches[0].pageX;
        } else {
            currPos = e.pageX;
        }
        clicked = true;
        return false;
    });
    $(document)
        .bind('mouseup touchend', function () {
        clicked = false;
    })
        .bind('mousemove touchmove', function (e) {
        if (clicked) {
            var pageX;
            if (e.type == "touchmove") {
                pageX = window.event.targetTouches[0].pageX;
            } else {
                pageX = e.pageX;
            }
            widthStep = 4;
            if (Math.abs(currPos - pageX) >= widthStep) {
                if (currPos - pageX >= widthStep) {
                    currImg++;
                    if (currImg > imageTotal) {
                        currImg = 1;
                    }
                } else {
                    currImg--;
                    if (currImg < 1) {
                        currImg = imageTotal;
                    }
                }
                currPos = pageX;
                $imgs.eq(lastImg).addClass('notseen');
                $imgs.eq(currImg).removeClass('notseen');
                lastImg = currImg;
                // $obj.html('<img src="' + aImages[options.currImg] + '" />');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, i cant get it work as you have it in the jsFiddle. Im overwriting what the original script was and loading the external file in my html head but it wont rotate for some reason.

Comment: Are you seeing any javascript errors (press F12 and look in the console)?

Comment: No there aren't any errors in the code, it just wont spin? not sure why. Im looking at in through the live code and it is changing the pictures out and from being seen and not seen but its not visually doing it

Comment: ha no i didnt, didnt think that was really important. It works now, thanks for the help.

Comment: LOL sorry, I added the css to my answer :P

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25016/discussion-between-user2055617-and-mottie)